# how to get files that has been created or updated after a particular file?

Tags: java, file

I have to get files those has been created or modified after a particular file.
I know the name of that particular file.

Answer (score 2):

What operating system?

1) Get the date that file was created

2) Then get the files that were created after that date

Answer (score 1):

To do this portably, use a combination of `File::list(...)`, `File::lastModified()` and `File::listRoots()` to walk the file-system. The execution could be time consuming, however. Some Unix operating systems have a daemon that can tell you about file modifications more efficiently; I assume the daemon taps into the file-system code.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

1) Get all the possibly relevant files.

2) Sort by creation date.

3) Get all files after your marker file.

Advantage: you only access the file system once.

Disadvantage: uses more memory.

Comment: how to get the creation date??

Comment: The actual creation date is not available in the standard Java API (AIUI some OSes do not provide it).  The best you can do is File.LastModified() which may be sufficient for you.  Otherwise there are a number of workrounds you can Google for specific to different Operating Systems.